# How do I combine Zend_Session and Zend_Oauth

Tags: zend-framework, oauth, doctrine-orm, zend-auth, zend-session

I'm having a problem with Zend_Auth and Zend_Session.  I recently broke my bootstrap file down into modular bootstraps.  Since then, whenever I login using Zend_Auth I get an error that the session has already been started.  So I changed my Zend_Auth namespace to 'DC_Auth'.  Now I'm getting a couple of errors.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Session_Exception' with message 'Zend_Session::start() - /home/digitalcivilian.com/subdomains/dev/app/library/Zend/Loader.php(Line:146): Error #2 include_once(): Failed opening 'Application/Proxies/User/Model/ProfileProxy.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/digitalcivilian.com/subdomains/dev/app/application/../library:/home/digitalcivilian.com/subdomains/dev/app/library:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') Array' in /home/digitalcivilian.com/subdomains/dev/app/library/Zend/Session.php:493 Stack trace: #0 /home/digitalcivilian.com/subdomains/dev/app/library/Zend/Session/Namespace.php(143): Zend_Session::start(true) #1 /home/digitalcivilian.com/subdomains/dev/app/library/Zend/Auth/Storage/Session.php(87): Zend_Session_Namespace->__construct('DC_Auth') #2 /home/digitalcivilian.com/subdomains/dev/app/application/Bootstrap.php(222): Zend_Auth_Storage_Session->__construct('DC_Auth') #3 /home/digitalcivilian.com/subdomains/dev/app/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(66 in /home/digitalcivilian.com/subdomains/dev/app/library/Zend/Session.php on line 493
```

The Proxy file (for Doctrine 2) that it can't find is actually at application/proxies/User_Model_ProfileProxy.php.

If you need anymore information please let me know, I've been having a hell of a time with this.

Edit:  An extra note, I can stop the zend session problems by putting Zend_Session::start() before I run my bootstrap in index.php.  But if I do that the session is started before my User module objects are loaded so the Zend_Auth identity ends up being a PHP_Incomplete_Object.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I had an ACL helper to work with dealing with access control.  I was adding that helper before loading the User module.  Which was causing issues with multiple things.  I moved that helper initialization to the end of the user module and I'm good to go.